# how to check if iMessage, group messaging on during runtime?

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage

I have an app which sends out Multiple SMS msgs.

Like we all know, if sending to a number which is recognised as a Apple phone, it will be sent as iMessage.

I dont want this in my App. So I would like to dis-able my app if iMessage is switched ON.

Is there a way to check if iMessage is switched on or off during runtime?

Comment: Is there any particular reason iMessage is verboten for this use case?

Comment: I want to send a BCC group SMS. if iMessage is switched on it will send group but everyone on the group msg will see everyone else's details. Which isn't very BCC at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [`MFMessageComposeViewController` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668), there is no such API. You can only check for the things specified in this API.